# Program that counts the number of syllables in a file

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I have a function that supposed to count the number of syllables in a file given these constraints:

1) Each group of adjacent vowels (a, e, i, o, u, y) counts as one syllable (for example, the “ea” in “real” counts as one syllable, but the “e..a” in “regal” count as two syllable

2) An “e” at the end of a word does not count as a syllable

3) Each word has at least one syllable even if the previous rules give a count of zero.

Given this, I made (albeit a pretty crummy) function to count the number of syllables in a file

I have tried creating this function in many different ways, but this way makes the most sense to me and also gives me a reasonable (not really but in the grand scheme of things it does) estimate of the true answer.

```
int syllableCount(char **str)
{
    int i = 0;
    int q = 0;
    int syllableCounter = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
    {
        for (q = 0; q <= strlen(str[i]); q++)
        {
            if (str[i][q] == 'A' || str[i][q] == 'a' ||
                str[i][q] == 'E' || str[i][q] == 'e' ||
                str[i][q] == 'I' || str[i][q] == 'i' ||
                str[i][q] == 'O' || str[i][q] == 'o' ||
                str[i][q] == 'U' || str[i][q] == 'u' ||
                str[i][q] == 'Y' || str[i][q] == 'y')
            {
                syllableCounter++;
            }
            if ((str[i][q] == 'E' && str[i][q + 1] == ' ') ||
                (str[i][q] == 'e' && str[i][q + 1] == ' ') ||
                (str[i][q] == 'E' && str[i][q + 1] == '\n') ||
                (str[i][q] == 'e' && str[i][q + 1] == '\n') ||
                (str[i][q] == 'E' && str[i][q + 1] == '.') ||
                (str[i][q] == 'e' && str[i][q + 1] == '.') ||
                (str[i][q] == 'E' && str[i][q + 1] == ';') ||
                (str[i][q] == 'e' && str[i][q + 1] == ';') ||
                (str[i][q] == 'E' && str[i][q + 1] == ':') ||
                (str[i][q] == 'e' && str[i][q + 1] == ':') ||
                (str[i][q] == 'E' && str[i][q + 1] == '!') ||
                (str[i][q] == 'e' && str[i][q + 1] == '!') ||
                (str[i][q] == 'E' && str[i][q + 1] == '?') ||
                (str[i][q] == 'e' && str[i][q + 1] == '?'))
            {
                syllableCounter--;
            }
            if ((str[i][q] == 'A' || str[i][q] == 'a' ||
                 str[i][q] == 'E' || str[i][q] == 'e' ||
                 str[i][q] == 'I' || str[i][q] == 'i' ||
                 str[i][q] == 'O' || str[i][q] == 'o' ||
                 str[i][q] == 'U' || str[i][q] == 'u' ||
                 str[i][q] == 'Y' || str[i][q] == 'y') &&
                (str[i][q + 1] == 'A' || str[i][q + 1] == 'a' ||
                 str[i][q + 1] == 'E' || str[i][q + 1] == 'e' ||
                 str[i][q + 1] == 'I' || str[i][q + 1] == 'i' ||
                 str[i][q + 1] == 'O' || str[i][q + 1] == 'o' ||
                 str[i][q + 1] == 'U' || str[i][q + 1] == 'u' ||
                 str[i][q + 1] == 'Y' || str[i][q + 1] == 'y'))
            {
                syllableCounter--;
            }
            if ((str[i][q] != 'A' || str[i][q] != 'a' ||
                 str[i][q] != 'E' || str[i][q] != 'e' ||
                 str[i][q] != 'I' || str[i][q] != 'i' ||
                 str[i][q] != 'O' || str[i][q] != 'o' ||
                 str[i][q] != 'U' || str[i][q] != 'u' ||
                 str[i][q] != 'Y' || str[i][q] != 'y') &&
                (str[i][q + 1] == ' ' || str[i][q + 1] == '\n'))
            {
                syllableCounter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return syllableCounter;
}
```

With my test file, I got 54 syllables and the real answer is 32. What is causing me to be off by 22!?

P.S: here's the text in the file I used:

"The red readymade dress was made for you!  It
was going to be ready tomorrow.  What was
the colour of the dress?  Oh, it was red!"

*All errors in spelling and spacing are done on purpose*

Comment: You might consider making a state machine.

Comment: Can you step through the code in a debugger? Try following along with it to make sure it counts each character correctly. It strikes me that the last condition (which seems to be for making sure that every word has at least one syllable) is very broken. It will count the `e` in `made` even though you're trying to ignore it with the earlier condition.

Comment: A little tip - at the start of the loop do `char curr = tolower(str[i][q])` to avoid double checking in all of the conditions

Comment: You need to refactor your code in order to avoid too much logic in one place.

I would suggest parsing lines for _words_ (whitespace separated tokens), and then parsing words for syllables, applying those rules on the syllables.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is way too complicated.

The rules in the original problem statement are incredibly simple.  For each word, you need to count how many distinct groups of vowels you encounter.  The suggestion in the comments of using a state machine is absolutely correct.  However, you do not need a complicated machine.  You just need to track a few basic states.

At a minimum, I suggest these states:

```
int in_word = 0;         // non-zero if currently processing a word
int in_vowels = 0;       // non-zero if currently processing group of vowels
int is_silent_e = 0;     // non-zero if the last vowel processed was an 'e'
int vowel_groups = 0;    // counts the number of vowel groups encountered in current word
```

Now, with sensible states as above, here's an outline of how to use them:

```
for (char *p = str[i], *end = p + strlen(str[i]) + 1; p != end; ++p)
{
    char c = tolower(*p);
    if (isalpha(c))
    {
        // starting a new word?
        if (!in_word) {
            in_word = 1;
            in_vowels = 0;
            is_silent_e = 0;
            vowel_groups = 0;
        }

        // do we have a vowel?
        if (strchr("aeiouy", c)) {
            if (!in_vowels) {
                /**** WRITE ME ****/
                ++vowel_groups;
            } else {
                /**** WRITE ME ****/
            }
        } else if (in_vowels) {
            // no longer in vowel group
            /**** WRITE ME ****/
        }
    }
    else if (in_word)
    {
        // No longer in a word -- update syllable count and reset
        vowel_groups -= is_silent_e;

        /**** WRITE ME ****/
    }
}
```

I have left some logic for you to fill in.  When you do this correctly, you will get the answer `32` for your example input.

Notice the special loop condition that ensures the string's null-terminator is also processed by the loop.  That will ensure that the end-of-word test will run even if the last character in the string is a word character.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I don't know anything about state machines so I have a few questions if that's okay. I don't really understand what's going on in the for loop, is it possible you could explain it a little more?

Comment: Which specific part of the for-loop are you asking about?  That loop contains pretty much the entire code that I supplied.  I wrote a working version and then removed parts that update the state variables so that you could learn by figuring it out.  Almost the entire problem you need to solve is now related to setting or clearing those state variables in an appropriate way.  Each variable has a meaning.  If you have a more specific question about something you don't understand, then fire away.

Comment: sorry I meant specifically the for loop like for(char *p = str[i], etc..) I don't really get what end is doing and why it is your condition

Comment: I mentioned it explicitly in the last paragraph.  It includes the string's null-terminator in the loop.  An alternative would be to use a do-while loop instead, avoiding the use of `strlen`.  _i.e._: `char *p = str[i]; do { .... } while(*p++ != '\0');`